# Django auth group model m2m

Tags: python, django

Recently, I have been working in a generic inscription system to help students to register in a class or a lab. But I have problems with the logic of ManyToManyField in the Lab class.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Day(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name


class LabName(models.Model):
    lab_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'LabNames'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.lab_name


class Lab(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(LabName)
    start_hour = models.TimeField()
    length = models.IntegerField(help_text="Given in minutes")
    classDays = models.ManyToManyField(Day)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    finish_date = models.DateField()
    max_cap = models.SmallIntegerField(help_text="Maximun number of students")
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="Teachers")
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Labs'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.id, self.name)
```

I would prefer to associate an specific Group (`django.contrib.auth.models.Group`) called 'Students' rather than all the users or at least filter and/or validate this field to just add and view students and also do the same with the teacher field.

**Update 1:** I just noticed that maybe I could filter those users who are in a certain group using the optional parameter `limit_choices_to`.

The question is:
How can I use the `limit_choices_to` parameter to show only those users who are in the 'Students' group or the 'Teachers' group?

[image]

Comment: I'm not understanding your question very well.. If you could elaborate / give examples (like pseudo code of your desired functionality) it would help me give you an answer.

Comment: @Yuji, Sorry for that is my first question and English is not my mother language. Also question updated :)

Comment: It turn out to be easier that what I thought:
I just edited this part:
`teacher = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="Teachers", limit_choices_to={'id__in' : Group.objects.all().get(name='Teachers').user_set.all()})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, see that's MUCH clearer.

I would re-write  `{'id__in' : Group.objects.all().get(name='Teachers').user_set.all()}`

to: 
`{'groups__name' : 'Teachers' }`

Also, if you would like to keep your admin functionality separated from your models more (did you know Admin was originally completely in the models?), you can use [formfield_for_foreignkey](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) which is certainly a nice way to keep your models separated from admin junk.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "teacher":
            kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Teacher')
        if db_field.name == "students":
            kwargs["queryset"] = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Student')
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```